# Get filename from file pointer

Tags: python

If I have a file pointer is it possible to get the filename?

```
fp = open("C:\hello.txt")
```

Is it possible to get `"hello.txt"` using `fp`?

Comment: Note that this isn't exactly a *file pointer*.  It's an instance of python's `file` type.

Comment: Pro tip: Use `dir()` on python objects to see what attributes are available. You'd have found `name` easily that way. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Or `help(fp)`, which gives you all of the docs for the file type and its methods and data.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. IMO the distinction between getting the file *path* and the file *name* is enough to justify letting this question stand on its own right; many Googlers landing here will benefit from the mention of `os.path.basename` in the answer which would be irrelevant on the other question.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

You can get the path via `fp.name`.  Example:

```
>>> f = open('foo/bar.txt')
>>> f.name
'foo/bar.txt'
```

You might need [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) if you want *only* the file name:

```
>>> import os
>>> f = open('foo/bar.txt')
>>> os.path.basename(f.name)
'bar.txt'
```

File object docs (for Python 2) [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects).

Comment: Correct answer, it was quite useful in getting the file name of uploaded file using Postman for REST API ([Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)) testing.

Comment: If the path passed in was a relative path, and the working directory changed `open` call, using `f.name` won't get you the right path, because it will give the path relative to the original working directory.