# Python accessing object variable

Tags: python

I have opened file in Python with code:

```
fileObject = open('file')
```

While debbuging in IDE I see that fileObject has many attributes such as:

> _CHUNK_SIZE, _finalizing, closed, encoding, ..., name, newlines

I would like to access the attribute `name`, because sometimes in huge programs, file name and path are generated, and I would like to get content of that attribute.

Comment: Is there a question somewhere?

Comment: I don't see any problem, probably you should also [try something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225557/get-filename-from-file-pointer), I mean, [anything](https://www.google.com/)

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't know how to translate my question and queries like "get object variable" or "get object properties" were pushing me to answers for questions like "how to pass argument to function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [1]: f = open('test')

In [2]: f.name
Out[2]: 'test'
```